# Meetings in the calendar is not getting updated in latest outlook (2019) in my OS-X Mojave

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macos-mojave

Even if I accept a meeting invite and go back to calendar, I'm unable to see the meeting there. I tried deleting the local cache and that resolved my issue, but I cannot keep doing that every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

1.What's email account type? Exchange or POP/IMAP?
2.Does it reoccur on Outlook on the Web? 
3.Does it reoccur on other version Outlook? Like Outlook 2016/2013 for Mac.

Try Refresh Calendar. In the Calendar app on your Mac, choose Show > Refresh Calendar.

Sometimes an interrupted Outlook profile might cause the issue. Re-create an Outlook profile for this user. Then check if this issue persists:

[Manage profiles or identities in Outlook for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-profiles-or-identities-in-outlook-for-mac-fed2a955-74df-4a24-bef6-78a426958c4c)